# OpenTelemetry collector - host.name is always localhost

Tags: linux, hostname

I use otelcol-contrib (v0.95.0) to retrieve system logs from many hosts and send them to a self-hosted OpenObserve instance. For 2 hosts, the field `host.name` is correctly set with the correct hostname, but for all other hosts, it always take 'localhost' as value.
The same behavior was observed with previous setup, using otelcol-contrib 0.93.0.

Here is a list of hosts :

| Host | Kind | OS | Arch | Retrieved host.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raspi2 | Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1 | Rasbian 11 | armv7l | raspi1 |
| raspi3 | Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 | Debian 11 | aarch64 | raspi2 |
| raspi4a | Raspberry Pi 4 Model B | Debian 12 | aarch64 | localhost |
| raspi4b | Raspberry Pi 4 Model B | Debian 12 | aarch64 | localhost |
| raspi4c | Raspberry Pi 4 Model B | Debian 12 | aarch64 | localhost |
| serv1 | Hetzner VM (CX21) | Rocky Linux 9.3 | x86_64 | localhost |
| serv2 | Hetzner VM (CX21) | Rocky Linux 9.3 | x86_64 | localhost |

All these hosts are configured the same way, using ansible (and Ansible detect the correct hostname in variable `ansible_hostname`).

The otelcol-contrib config file is the following :

```yaml
receivers:
  filelog/std:
    include: [ /var/log/**log ]

processors:
  resourcedetection/system:
    detectors: ["system"]
    system:
      hostname_sources: ["os"]
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_percentage: 75
    spike_limit_percentage: 15
  batch:
    send_batch_size: 10000
    timeout: 10s

extensions:
  zpages: {}
  memory_ballast:
    size_mib: 512

exporters:
  otlphttp/openobserve:
    endpoint: {{ openobserve_url }}
    headers:
      Authorization: "Basic {{ openobserve_api_key }}"

service:
  extensions: [zpages, memory_ballast]
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [filelog/std]
      processors: [resourcedetection/system, memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp/openobserve]
```

On each host, the command `hostname` returns the right value.

So, how does `host.name` is retrieved and why otelcol retrieve the value `localhost` on some host and the correct value on others ? Is there something invalid in my config file, or should I check some host-specific configuration to help otelcol retrieve the right value ?